# linux: как удалить много файлов в папке?

Tags: linux, debian, find

У меня есть папка с файлами сессий, которые почему не очищаются. Из-за этого их стало очень много. Из-за этого стал подвисать сервер. Хотел удалить файлы, оставив только те, которым нету 30 дней

```
find /home/admin/tmp/ -atime +30 | xargs rm -f
```

Все зависло, нагрузка выросла в разы, стали отказывать сайты. Остановил команду.

Как я понял, эта команда должна сначала построить дерево, после этого начнет удалять. Но видимо оно не может даже дерево построить, так как файлов слишком много.

Есть ли какой то другой способ?

Comment: Вообще-то find сам умеет удалять (`-delete`)

Comment: Если все ещё будет тормозить попробуйте понизить приоритет. См. команды nice и ionice

Comment: `find /path1 /path2 -name failed*.* -type f -exec rm {} \;`. Подпилите под свои потребности. Пайп с xargs также будет работать, но там из-за буфера происходит "подвисон" скорее всего по этой причине: [enSO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165160/how-does-bash-pipe-large-amounts-of-data#165163)

Comment: пробовал вот так - ionice -c 3 -n 7 find /home/admin/tmp -type f -name 'sess_*' -ctime +30 -delete
- тоже зависает(

Comment: Он не зависает, а удаляет. Подождите хотя бы час. А сессии храните в memcached или, если сервер перезагружается, хотя бы раскидывайте по подкаталогам.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить с timeout